# Selecting a single field from a MySQL database for comparison of a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get 'groupLeader' field from the table 'groups' in the database and store it in a variable and then compare to the current logged in username but I get the error:

> Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/content/00/7923300/html/uber/tasks.php on line 31

The code I currently have is this:

```
$sq = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupID='".$groupID."'";
$result=$db->query($sq);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $gLeader=  mysql_result($result, $i, 'groupLeader');
    $i++;
}
if($_COOKIE['$username'] == $gLeader) {
    echo "User is leader.";
}
```

Forgive me if this seems like a rather simple request. I'm new to php and working with databases.

EDIT: Forgot to mention line 31 is the line that contains

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

Comment: "mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" indicates the $result is not populated with the result set which means your query did not work as you expected. Try printing the query and directly run it. Also, you should move to mysqli methods.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use with PHP's mysql_query or your framework row number method.

```
 $result = mysql_query($sq);
```

Or perhaps

```
 $db->number_of_rows($sq);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, the query is not executed properly for an unknown reason. That is why it is returning ***False*** to `$result`, which is really not a resource.

use:

```
$sq = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupID='".$groupID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sq);
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query($sq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of that code is redundant and pointless. if all you want is a single field from a single row, then don't do `SELECT *`, and don't use a loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT groupLeader FROM ..."
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($reuslt);
   if ($row['groupLeader'] == $_COOKIE['username']) {
       ...
   }
}
```

However, note that the mysql_*() function complex is officially deprecated in PHP and should not be used anymore. Consider switching to mysqli instead, which is generally drop-in compatible, or better yet, use PDO instead.